# Crystal Reports Sub Report Stored Procedure parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a main report with 20 sub reports. Main report and sub reports all use stored procedures.

In my main report, the parameters are @startdate and @enddate. In one of my sub reports, the stored procedure has an @enddate parameter, I am trying to link the @enddate parameter in my main report to the @enddate parameter in my sub report. I cant seem to do this with out crystal prompting me to enter the sub report enddate separately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually connect the `@enddate` parameter in the main report to each one in the subreport--there isn't a wizard or easier way to do this in CR.  Steps:

- right click a subreport
- select 'change subreport links...'
- select the `@enddate1 parameter from the Available Fields list and move it to the Field to link to list
- choose `@enddate` from subreport parameter field to use
- click OK
- repeat for each subreport

If you are handy with the SDK, you could do this in code.

Comment: HI Craig, thanks, im using CR2011. When you say "link them manually" do you mean doing this by changing in the selection formula's? I have tried that and it still prompts for the date parameter. Thanks